# How can I create an AngularJS datepicker that selects two dates (a 2-week pay period) when the user clicks one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, datepicker

When I click a date with the datepicker, it then shows the date: 2015-07-05 in the input box.
  I would like to somehow display the following in the text box: 2015-06-29 – 2015-07-14, when the user clicks on July 5th. The text box is not supposed to only display the date, but the 2-week pay period that the date is in.

The code I currently have is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control te-pay-period-textbox" style="width:207px" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd — yyyy-mm-dd" ng-model="CJPMD.c_jpM_DATE_1" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" datepicker-options="dateOptions" max-date="'2020-06-22'" min-date="minDate" is-open="opened1" datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}">
<img style="HEIGHT: 34px; WIDTH: 36px; MARGIN-TOP:18px; margin-left:10px;" alt="Datepicker Placeholder" src="images/icon-date-picker.png" ng-click="open1($event)" /></a></td>
```

**ANGULARJS CONTROLLER**

```
     $scope.open1 = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.opened1 = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1,
    };
    $scope.formats = ['yyyy/MM/dd'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        $("CalendarToggleShow").toggleClass("CalendarToggle");
    });
```

I know I don't have a lot, I am pretty new to this stuff and just need some help. Thank you so much!

Comment: since dates are fixed why can't you just calculate them and have separate scope variable to display them? Sort of like `you picked Jul 5, it falls in period {{otherVar}}`. Can use a library like `moment.js` to help calculate the dates

Comment: I would suggest messing around with either this library
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date
or this one
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker
I worked with both, and really what you want to do will just be a matter of simple math, and then updating the inputs.